# How can I order a list composed of class instances based on an individual argument?

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am creating a program to compare different students, and as such, I need to rank them according to their GPAs. I started by creating a students class, then creating individual instances, with which I will work and add to a list:

```
class Students:
"""A class meant to simulate a high school student"""
    def __init__(self, gpa, first_choice, second_choice)

student01 = Students(16, universities.a, universities.b)
student02 = Students(15, universities.b, universities.a)
student03 = Students(18, universities.a, universities.c)
```

However, once I add the students to a list, order it, and attempt to print it, it does not return the names I have assigned:

```
student_applicants = [student01, student02, student03]
ordered_student_applicants = sorted(student_applicants, key=operator.attrgetter('gpa'))
```

It returns:

```
[<students.Students object at 0x106139370>, <students.Students object at 0x106139760>, <students.Students object at 0x10607e340>, <students.Students object at 0x10607e5e0>]
[<students.Students object at 0x106139760>, <students.Students object at 0x10607e340>, <students.Students object at 0x106139370>, <students.Students object at 0x10607e5e0>]
```

Instead of:

```
[student01, student02, student03]
[student02, student01, student03]
```

How can I make it so that it ranks each student instance, while returning each one with the original name assigned (e.g. student01)

Comment: ``<students.Students object at 0x106139370>`` is merely Python's default representation of objects, since it does not know what information is relevant (and safe) to be displayed. The information *put into the objects* is still there, and you could make the object use it as the default representation. However, *none* of the names of the objects are known to the object, so they cannot be displayed – at least not without extensive, inefficient introspection. Do you *really* need to display the variable names? How about giving the objects a name field to display?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and it worked (adding a 'name' field to the object to display. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does sort the student instances and prints the list correctly.

The name of the variable `student01` is local. It is not recoreded anywhere.

If you want to keep that name, you should either use a mapping such as a dict:

```
{
    "student01": Students(16, universities.a, universities.b),
    ...
}
```

or make the name an attribute of the instance:

```
class Students:
"""A class meant to simulate a high school student"""
    def __init__(self, name, gpa, first_choice, second_choice):
        ...


student01 = Students("student01", 16, universities.a, universities.b)
```

In the second case, you can then print the names rather than the instances:

```
ordered_student_applicants = sorted(student_applicants, key=operator.attrgetter('gpa'))
print([s.name for s in ordered_student_applicants])
```